# Multipart form data is not working in react native

Tags: react-native, multipart

I'm trying to make an api call with multipart as content-type. when I added the params to FormData, it is creating multiple array lists.

```
 var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('name', "Mahendra")
formData.append('number', "12131233123")
formData.append('image', {uri : pathToImage, name : "image", "type":"image/jpeg"})
console.log(formData)
```

When I log the request, I'm getting multiple arrays inside. Below is the request

```
{"_parts" : [["name","Mahendra"],["number","12131233123"],["image",{"uri":"/Users/XXXXC/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/XXXXX/data/Containers/Data/Application/XXX/tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/asdas3D4.jpg","name":"image","type":"image/jpeg"}]]}
```

Can someone help me on this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure to understand at which point you log them, but following the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) docs, you shouldn't access the value directly but through the api methods. To send the data you have to use either `XMLHttpRequest.send()` or the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have just logged the formData before sending it to the fetch method.